# Split excel data by key using javaScript

Tags: javascript, json, excel, lodash

I am pulling data from Excel using JavaScript. The output looks like this.

```
{
    
    "Responsible": "Grey",
    "Goal": 0.823,
    "Jan": 0.8621397507374327,
    "Feb": 0.8605700219733681,
    "Mrz": 0.8870898346258058,
    "Apr": 0.8529801908413164,
    "Mai": 0.8507431241640211
  }
```

I want to split the data into the following :

```
         {   
            "Responsible": "Grey",
            "Goal": 0.823,
            "Month": 0.8621397507374327,  
          }


         {  
           "Responsible": "Grey",
            "Goal": 0.823,
            "Month": 0.8605700219733681,
         }
         
         {   
            "Responsible": "Grey",
            "Goal": 0.823,
            "Month": 0.8870898346258058, 
          }


         {  
           "Responsible": "Grey",
            "Goal": 0.823,
            "Month": 0.8529801908413164,
         }

         {  
           "Responsible": "Grey",
            "Goal": 0.823,
             "Month": 0.8507431241640211
         }
```

My code looks like this :

```
Ausgabe = [];     

_.forEach(data, element => {  
  obj = {
     
    Responsible: element.Responsible,
    Goal: element["Goal \r\n2022"]  ,
    Jan : element["Jan-22"],
    Feb: element["Feb-22"],
    Mrz : element["Mar-22"],
    Apr : element["Apr-22"],
    Mai : element["May-22"],
    
  }
  Ausgabe.push(obj)
    

})
```

The data is provided in the data field, which can be edited or overwritten and is returned by default at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use destructuring to extract `Responsible`, `Goal` and the rest of the object's properties. Use `Object.entries()` to get an array of `[key, value]` pairs from `rest`, and iterate it with `Array.map()` to create the objects:

```js
const fn = ({ Responsible, Goal, ...rest }) =>
  Object.entries(rest)
    .map(([k, v]) => ({
      Responsible,
      Goal,
      [k]: v
    }))

const obj = { "Responsible": "Grey", "Goal": 0.823,  "Jan": 0.8621397507374327, "Feb": 0.8605700219733681, "Mrz": 0.8870898346258058, "Apr": 0.8529801908413164, "Mai": 0.8507431241640211 }

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

If you just want the month's value, use `Object.values()` instead of entries:

```js
const fn = ({ Responsible, Goal, ...rest }) =>
  Object.values(rest)
    .map(Month => ({
      Responsible,
      Goal,
      Month
    }))

const obj = { "Responsible": "Grey", "Goal": 0.823,  "Jan": 0.8621397507374327, "Feb": 0.8605700219733681, "Mrz": 0.8870898346258058, "Apr": 0.8529801908413164, "Mai": 0.8507431241640211 }

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi this worked well thanks! I edited the question because I wanted a different output originally. Any suggestion on this ?

Comment: See updated answer